# Regex C#. Match specific substring and return that substring only

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've been pulling my hair out over this, and I think I am quite close to actually getting it to work but I just can't seem to.

I've been attempting to pull out a specific substring from a string using Regex. This substring must match a certain set of strings/digits. Then after this, it should be returned to another function which will pull out the number only.

Here's some examples of strings that are present

```
"(DEV #198) I am a dev testing 23 different things."
"(dev #9540) I am a dev testing different other things."
"(FQ #1140) I am a dev testing different things."
"(fq #910) I am a dev testing different other things."
```

In the end I would like to have 198, 9540, 1140 or 910 as the final variable depending on the input.

Here is my Regex so far. I think it's close, but I need some help. (note the double backslashes for C#).

```
^(?=.*?\\b(dev|DEV|fq|FQ)\\b)(?=.*?\\b[0-9]{3,4}\\b).*$
```

Here is the fragment of code I'm using also.

```
string caseNumber = cpTicket.Desc;
string regexPattern = "^(?=.*?\\b(dev|DEV|fq|FQ)\\b)(?=.*?\\b[0-9]{3,4}\\b).*$";
caseNumber = Regex.Match(caseNumber, regexPattern).ToString();
```

That's as far as I have got with this. If you can help, I will be so grateful :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
(?<=(?:dev|fq) #)\d+
```

- `(?<=)`: This is a look behind to make sure the digits are preceded with what is inside the look behind.
- `(?:dev|fq)`: This matches either `dev` or `fq`.
- `#`: Matches a space which is followed by a hash `#`.
- `\d+`: Matches one or more digits.

Turn case insensitivity mode on so `dev` and `fq` could match in all cases.

You can turn case insensitivity from within the regular expression itself like this:

```
(?i)(?<=(?:dev|fq) #)\d+
```

In C#:

```
var input = "(DEV #198) I am a dev testing 23 different things.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?i)(?<=(?:dev|fq) #)\d+");
```

Notice how you can use the `@` before the string to create what is called a verbatim string  so you don't have to double escape everything.

Comment: Ah awesome, this worked great! Thankyou so much, I see that I was quite far off in my own implementation!

Comment: Instead of using `(?i)`, you can use `(?i:dev|fq)`

Comment: @PierlucSS Thank you for your feedback, I didn't know you could nest the flag like that inside the non-matching group, I wish I could give you a vote up for this as you deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you pattern can simply be:

```
"\(.*?\#(\d*)\)"
```

This will match the group in brackets and return the number.

```
 var m = Regex.Match(input, @"\(.*?\#(\d*)\)");
 if (m.Groups.Count > 0)
 {
     string matchedNumber = m.Groups[1].Value;
 }
```

Comment: Ah yeah this works, and it returns the both the DEV #<number> and the number by itself. Both answers were great but I can only mark one as the correct one :( Otherwise I would mark both of you.